# Insert an element into a range

Tags: c++, c++20

What is the right implementation of `Insert` method in the code below?

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template <std::ranges::range Range>
class Processor
{
public:

    using T = std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>;

    void Insert(Range range, T val)
    {
        //add val into range
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    Processor<std::vector<int>> p;
    p.Insert(v, 5);

    std::set<int> set;

    Processor<std::set<int>> p1;
    p.Insert(set, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to insert to `vector` and `set` with the same code? (insertion into `vector` is probably `push_back`)

Comment: Does it matter where, in your `std::vector`, an item would be inserted?

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, it should be inserted to the end of the `vector`

Comment: Last I checked ranges were adaptors and thus were views, they don't modify anything... you'd need the container to insert.

Comment: @Mgetz what is `std::ranges::output_range` than?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky that's a concept, but generally speaking all the ranges in `<ranges>` are adaptors. So in theory you could implement a container that satisfies that concept. But my point was more the standard adaptors in the library (what most people think of as "ranges") are just views. So strictly speaking you could constrain your template with that. That may satisfy your needs. But I'm not sure what implements that concept right now.

Comment: @Mgetz my first idea was that `std::ranges::output_range` probably contains an output iterator, but actually I do not understand what is it.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky `std::ranges::output_range` is just a concept, basically a description of a constraint on code you're using in a template. All it requires is that whatever that thing is both a range and an output iterator. As it turns out my hunch that `std::back_inserter` could work... doesn't because it doesn't satisfy `std::ranges::range` e.g. that `std::ranges::begin` and `std::ranges::end` is valid for it.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky So I was able to get `std::ranges::output_range` to work on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/shvP4on8a) but it's not inserting... it's replacing. You can't insert into a range, just replace segments of it. I was going to put this into an answer but it's not an answer to the asked question.

Comment: You may use constexpr if to check if range is a vector and then use push_back and if it is an set insert.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to insert to vector and set with the same code? (insertion into vector is probably push_back)

If you want to call the same function for set and vector you could try this soultion using templates, constexpr if and std::same_as.
example:

```cpp
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
template <typename Range, typename T>
void
insertInSetOrVector (Range &range, T const &t)
{
  if constexpr (std::same_as<std::vector<T>, Range>)
    {
      range.push_back (t);
    }
  else if constexpr (std::same_as<std::set<T>, Range>)
    {
      range.insert (t);
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  auto vec = std::vector<int>{};
  insertInSetOrVector (vec, 42);
  auto set = std::set<int>{};
  insertInSetOrVector (set, 42);
  std::cout << "vector: " << vec.at (0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "set has 42: " << (set.count (42) == 1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
vector: 42
set has 42: true
```

edit: thanks for the suggestion (set.count (42) == 1) is more accurate.